# How can I find Simulink Executable on my computer?

Tags: matlab, executable, simulink

After I generate code with `Simulink Coder` choosing `grt.tlc` target Matlab gives me this adres as executable's adress. `C:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2013a\sys\lcc\bin\lcclnk -s -LC:/PROGRA~1/MATLAB/R2013a\sys\lcc\lib  -o ../untitled.exe` What does it mean? What am I supposed to do when I get a misterious adress like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing *"mysterious"*

Your executable is at

`../untitled.exe`

meaning `untitled.exe` is present in one folder above the current working folder, probably the place where the simulink model resides

`-o` is used for output file name given to linker.

Comment: Now I found it. Thank you very much.